# How can I replace string in KSH file from a sql file?

Tags: sql, ksh

Here is my code in ksh file

```
current_year=$(date +%Y)
current_month=$(date +%m)
sql=$(cat $script_path | sed -i 's/&1/current_year/g' | sed -i 's/&2/current_month/g')
```

Fisrt, I `cat` a sql file in KSH file and then I want the a string called `"&1"` and `"&2"` in sql file are replaced by `current_year` and `current_month`. But it doesn't work, hope I can find a solution here, thanks very much.

The reason I did that is I don't want to pass the parameter to sql file from ksh file, I just want a simple way to replace the string in ksh file.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your script to:

```
script_path=script.txt

current_year=$(date +%Y)
current_month=$(date +%m)
sql=$(sed -e "s/\&1/${current_year}/g" \
    -e "s/\&2/${current_month}/g" "${script_path}")
echo "${sql}"
```

- You don't need `cat`, I put it as a stdin read (`< ${script_path}`) for `sed`.
- Search and replace for `sed` is `-e` not `-i` which is for inline editing.
- Use double quotes, not single quotes. That allows variable substitution.
- Escape the &, by doing `\&` so it isn't interpreted.

Here is a sample input file and the result:

```
# cat script.txt; ksh sq.sh
select * from &1 where &2;
select script.txt sq.sh from 2022 where 09;
```